# In MVC5, how can we use different user logins + roles (and databases) for different areas (back office and web)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization, area

we're stuck. We're puzzling about how to best handle this problem. What would be 'best practice'?

What we need is a push in the right direction. What we want/need is to have different user logins for different MVC areas. And it should (preferably) be possible to be logged in with different users to different areas at the same time. One area is the back office / CMS area, only accessible by admin's, editors, developers, etc. has it's own user database. The other area is a 'website' that is running on it, using an anonymous user (or the currently logged in content editor user) to fetch content from the back office area's REST webservices. This area also has it's own database of users, different roles, that database could be on the other side of the world (figuratively speaking). The [Authorize] attribute will not help much I guess. Or well, we're thinking of creating a special Authorize attribute for the content editor area. In our search for a solution or products solving a similar problem we found that Umbraco is using an UmbracoAuthorizeAttribute to do this.

But this would not solve the problem of supporting 2 login pages and being redirected to area's login page when someone is not logged in to that area. Or how should we handle that?

Is there anyone that could give us a push into the right direction and also tell us what we should think about/be careful with when implementing it? We don't 'need' a complete solution.

[Edit]
Could using Claims be a solution to our predicament? Would that be the right thing to do?

[Edit2]
Also the website area and content editor area should act as two different websites as much as possible. The content editor is allowed having to jump through loops, duck and dive. The website should be able to use whatever authorization mechanizm that is available.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The `[Authorize]` attribute will work for you just fine.  However, you will need to assign roles to your users and then apply the `[Authorize(Roles="Rolename")]` attribute to the controllers for those areas.

For instance,  you may have an Admin area, and in Admin you have a `UsersController` that is used to manage users.  You would apply `[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]` to your `UsersController` class (and any other controllers in the Admin area).

Next, you neeed to assign roles to users, so that users with those roles can access those areas.  How you do that, depends on what kind of authentication you're using.  If you're using Windows Authentication, then you need to give them a security group by that name.  If you're using Identity or Membership, then you need to enable the proper role management functionality and add the user to the role using the appropriate api when you register the user (and add management functionality to the admin tools).

In this way, a user can be assigned multiple roles, and they can be given access to whatever areas based on the role(s) you give them.

As for why you think it won't work for your other situation, i'm unsure.  It sounds like you have two different authentication mechanisms, which is fine as long as they both create standard GenericPrincipals and Identities.

In my opinion, people are way too quick to jump to the "Custom Authorization Attribute" approach, when it's really the wrong thing to do.  The standard Authorization Attribute is very flexible because it works with the generic IPrincipal/IIdentity and any authentication that can create those objects will work with it, without changing the attribute.

Comment: Yes exactly we've got 2 entirely different authentication mechanisms. Users from one database/source are not know in the other. Users in both databases can have a admin roles. Have admin rights in the one area but no access to the other (this could potentially be solved using different naming). I've just starting thinking about maybe using claims and drop the use of roles (codewise). Could that be a solution?

Comment: @It'sme...Alex - as I said, the [Authorize] attribute doesn't care where your authorization comes from, just so long as it creates a valid IPrincipal/IIdentity, You can use claims, or you can use anything else

Comment: For us the thing is that the 2 area's should act like 2 different websites as much as possible. The 'website' area should not have to bother with the content editor (cms). It should be allowed to use whatever authorization mechanizm that is available.

Comment: @It'sme...Alex - Yes, and as I have said, several times now (i'm not sure why you're not understanding this), you CAN use any authentication, as long as it creates an IPrincipal/IIdentity.  You can setup your areas to do whatever you want.  You just give access to the users of one database one set of roles and the users for the other a different set of roles.

Comment: I do understand what you mean :-) remember we've been thinking about this subject as well. The thing is having roles controlling it makes the 2 authentication methods sort of dependent on each other. Having to be careful with role names, makes them having to be aware of each other and thus in some way binds them. We could automatically add some 'area role', but somehow I have something against hard coding roles ... then again my personal feelings don't count :-) we have to come up with a solution that works and always works, without conditions. We will discus your solution with the team.

Comment: We've discussed it and we've looked at the internal workings of the AuthorizeAttribute. But using roles would not solve our 2 login pages problem. Having been logged in to 1 area should redirect you to the other area's login page when trying to enter the other. But we might be overlooking something :-)

Comment: @It'sme...Alex - redirection has nothing to do with roles, or the Authorize attribute.  This happens in your login page.  After you set the cookie, you specify where they redirect to.  That is entirely up to you.

Comment: @It'sme...Alex - the problem here is that you keep telling me about a problem, and every time I tell you that it's not a problem, and why, you tell me about  a different problem... You haven't given us all the information obviously.

Comment: @It'sme...Alex - it sounds to me more like you want a runtime-replaceable security system, which is an entirely different beast from what you're talking about (You say you don't want to hard code any role names).  That's a huge undertaking, and something MVC doesn't provide any support for out of the box.